# PHP- How do you split up an array of different rows thats been put in as one?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to make a shopping cart and have managed to submit what checkboxes a user has checked to my shopping cart page. It echos the details from the database but I've realised that I cant get my details to post through on their own.

There is one big group, is there a way to add to my code to ungroup them and put them in a table?

this is the code ive used to post the deatils to my cart:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['games'])) {
    $n = count($_POST['games']);
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
        echo $_POST['games'][$i];
    } 
?>
```

this is the database:

```
  <?php
        $con = pg_connect(bla bla);
        if (!$con){
            die('Could not connect: ' . pg_error());
        }

        $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM CSGames");
        echo "
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>";

        while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
            echo"<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="' . $row['0'] . $row['1'] . $row['2'] . $row['3'] . $row['4'] . '"/></td>';

            echo"</tr>";      
        }
        echo"</table>";

        pg_close($con);

        ?>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you first code snippet has to do with the second.  I am also unclear on really what you are asking.

Comment: well the first code is takes the value of the Checkbox and posts it but it posts it in one big chunk and i need it to post out each $row speretly so i cant put it in to a table

Comment: The first code doesn't do any kind of POST'ing at all.  It just echos out a POST variable. There is no reference to $_POST['games'] in your second snippet at all. The second snippet seems to get its data from a totally different data source (that database). The relation between the database query and the POST'ed data is not at all clear.

Comment: oops really sorry forgot to add this,

Comment: <form action="cart.php" method="post">
       Add to cart <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
       <?php include 'database_connection.php' ?>
       </form>

Comment: You should update your question with the additional code, though I still don't see how the data from `$_POST['games']` is supposed to fit in with the table you are building.  I can see how the table would build the POST though. You ask about ungrouping "them" what is "them"? This POST variable? The data from the database?  What do you mean by "ungroup"? You already seem to be making a table row for every record from the database. I don't understand what the values in the database are that you are concatenating into the checboxes "value" property.

Comment: Basically you haven't described what you are trying to do in a real world sense.

Comment: i can see im not very good at explanine my self so maybe if you could see what ive done and its  output for yourself it might make sence, if you type this is http://users.aber.ac.uk/edd14/cs25010/index.php and login with anything, check a few boxes and add to cart you will the output im trying to ungroup, i would be so greatful

Comment: OK so all you care about is making the output look pretty?  Will work up an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the data you are getting from `$_POST['games']` lies in how you are populating the 'value' property of the input.

While personally I would add a game ID to your database table and only put the value of the game's ID as the input's value and just look up the data for the selected games on your cart output page, I will stick with the framework within how you have done things for my answer.

This is your problem:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="' . $row['0'] . $row['1'] . $row['2'] . $row['3'] . $row['4'] . '"/>
```

Here you are just concatenating a bunch of strings together without any sort of separator that you can later split on.  I would simply suggest doing something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="' . $row['0'] . '|||' . $row['1'] . '|||' . $row['2'] . '|||'. $row['3'] . '|||' . $row['4'] . '"/>
```

I have added triple pipes `|||` that you can later use to split these fields on.

So when you get to outputting, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['games'])) {
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    foreach($_POST['games'] as $game_string) {
        $game = explode('|||', $game_string);
?>
    <tr>
<?php
        foreach ($game as $attr) {
?>
         <td><?php echo $attr; ?></td>
<?php
        }
?>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
} 
?>
```